# How can I take care that the -> is after the text

Tags: css

I have this page : https://ticketee-wissel.c9users.io/projects/new 
So you can see the arrow is now under the text.

How can I make it work that the arrow is after the text and still see the arrow move on hover ?

Comment: Works for me, did you fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Any code related to your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you. If the question doesn't make sense and can't be answered without the link, it's not appropriate for this site. Instead, put the [**minimum** complete example](/help/mcve) in the question.

Comment: @raarts : I did not fix anything. On which browser did you look. I work with FF. oke, on Edge it looks well on FF not

Comment: So I need to place the whole form code and all the css files. That will be a very big paste

Comment: check out mine solution workin fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply add

```
display: inline-block;
```

to your parent button.

further add

```
.arrow-button .arrow-cont{
height: 20px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

here height depends on your button element, using it only to vertically align with button text.

Comment: For some reason, the animation is not working then

Comment: @Rokin , thnx , done re- edit

Comment: oke, so the display : inline-block needs to be in .button ?

Comment: @user1052732 no that will create issues with other buttons , i can see u have lot of classes added for that button : arrow-button arrow-button--right arrow-button--out   , add that to any one of them whichever suits you better